# Block highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, block, syntax-highlighting

I tried to do syntax highlighting in vim, but I've got weird color highlighting letters on blocks. On black, it is not much of a problem, but when it's sunny blue, it's not readable, so I would prefer a light background.

`~/.vimrc` does not seem to respond to `set background=light` if there is no colorscheme.
I'm not very proficient with vim, and I think I might have turned on a function inadvertently, by accidental key strokes. Is there a way to turn off all kind of search and highlight?

I'm reading readmes, but this makes it difficult. The image below shows my screen.
[image: Vim view]

Comment: If this persists from session to session, it's probably something you put in your vimrc.

Comment: Part of the problem may be search highlighting.  If so, the `:noh` will be a step in the right direction.  You can get an idea where the colors are coming from by using the example under `:help synID()`.  If that does not shed any light, then keep looking at your terminal settings, as @Ingo Karkat suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about such incomplete screen updates occurring then the value of `$TERM` isn't right. Especially inside a *screen* / *tmux* session, be sure to have set the correct value (`screen-256color` in that latter case).

You could try GVIM (the non-terminal GUI version of Vim) to get moving with your work; it shouldn't have those issues.

> I think I might have turned on a function inadvertently, by accidental key strokes

Fear not, any settings only persist by editing the `~/.vimrc` file (or by saving a session). You'll always get a clean new instance by quitting and re-starting Vim.

Comment: it is the same physically on the machine. With nothing in the .vimrc there is a only little yellow blocks behind each colon as above pic and then if I put `syntax on` and `colorscheme solarized` (say) I get the yellow blocks and the additional blocks of text. I tried various schemes with same result. Do you think it might be issue with xterm itself ? I forget where to look for that.

Comment: Please tell us more about your system (OS / Linux distribution name, version, Vim version, terminal, value of `$TERM`).

Comment: OK if I look at the same files as root everything looks the way it should do so is likely something in my profile ?

Comment: is fedora18: vim 7.3: terminal Gnome 3.6.1: putty on win8: I'm looking to see what $term means. I put xterm-256color in my .bashrc

Comment: I made a new user and they(me) have the same issue

Comment: Well, then you should be able to solve this by comparing the settings (.bashrc, .profile, .vimrc) of root and the other users. `echo $TERM` gives you the value of it.

Comment: oops; I told a lie, I didn't have syntax on in root .vimrc. It is the same problem for root.

Comment: it seems to be something to do with highlight search. when hls is on even in gvim I get the colons highlighted in yellow but with `set nohls` that goes away.